# Is it possible to define countability without referring the natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Cantor defined countable sets as

> A set is countable if there exists an injective function from the set to the set of natural numbers.

Still today countability is almost always defined in Cantor's words. Are the natural numbers really necessary to define countability. Most mathematicians admit that set theory is still a rich subject to study without getting into the conception of numbers. And I believe that the notion of countability is more fundamental than the set of natural numbers itself. Hence I wonder is it possible to define countability without referring the natural numbers?

Let $A$ be a set and let $S:A\rightarrow A$ be a successor function which is characterised by the following properties.

1. Two different elements in $A$ can not have same successor.
2. The successor of an element should not be its ancestor.

Shall I define countable sets as below?

> A set is countable if there exists a successor function as characterised above.

Comment: for the set $\mathbb R$ isn't the function $S(x)=x+1$ a successor function?

Comment: @lulu Yes it is. And what is the answer to the question? Is it possible to define countability without referring $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Well, $\mathbb N$ seems pretty fundamental to me.  I don't see any way to dodge it that doesn't just end up being a just a way to disguise it.  Doesn't mean there isn't a way, of course.

Comment: "And I believe that the notion of countability is more fundamental than the set of natural numbers itself." Out of curiosity, why do you believe that? I certainly think the exact opposite.

Comment: @Noah Schweber The literal meaning of count or countability must be ignored. I don't know whether current mathematical definition for countability is rooted in that literal meaning. If that meaning is ignored then my belief may have some sense.

Comment: @DurgadassS I guess I still don't understand - why do you expect countability to be more natural than the natural numbers? What property of countability stands out? I'm just curious where you're coming from in this regard. That is - what is your interest in this question motivated by in the first place?

Comment: @Noah Schweber I believe that if an element is able to be distinguished from others I am able to pick that out. To pick an element natural numbers are not needed. However to count I assign a natural number while picking. To pick is not to count but counting always require nothing more than picking. Meaning if a set is pickable it is countable, in my intuition.

Comment: It strikes me as the definition of "ancestor" in your system could be tricky without an axiom to let you collapse an arbitrarily large number of steps into one the way induction does for natural numbers.

Comment: I'm no set-theorist, but what about adding the following to the list of axioms?
   3. Given any two distinct elements of A, one must be a successor of the other.

Comment: @JamesM: What does it mean "a successor of the other"? If you mean "you can get to it by applying the successor function finitely many times", then you invariably have to know what are the natural numbers to even formulate this.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not necessarily I think, successor is just a function or a special kind of relation which is characterised by the axioms. The third axiom given by James is a well known property -- the connectedness property.

Comment: The term "successor" is usually reserved to an unary function symbol. In turn, that induces a relation which is a linear order under the "usual axioms associated with a successor operation". But this order is not definable in the language of just the successor operation, it requires some second-order definition. If you just treat "successor" as "larger", then you have something more akin to a linear order, in which case there is no difference between your suggestion axioms and any linear order with a minimal element.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am not a proffessional mathematician. The question is just due to intuition (might be a stupid one). However, your comment indicates that I have to study more stuffs. By the way the answer is nice :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes. You can. Depending on the available tools.

1. A set $A$ is countable if and only if whenever $B\subseteq A$ and $|B|<|A|$, then $B$ is finite. If you want countable to refer only to infinite sets, then you can also add that there is a proper subset of $A$ which is equipotent with $A$.

   Now, you might argue that finiteness depend on the natural numbers, but don't worry, Tarski got you covered: $X$ is finite if and only if the partial order $(\mathcal P(X),\subseteq)$ is well-founded.
2. A set $A$ is countable if and only if it can be linearly ordered such that every proper initial segment is finite. Again, if you are only interested in infinite sets, add the requirement that there is no maximal element.

Comment: Interestingly, this whole thing doesn't even require the axiom of choice!

Comment: Using this definition, is it possible to prove $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable? If so can you give some links to such proofs

Comment: Why wouldn't you? You asked for ***equivalent*** definitions of countability which do not presuppose some notion of natural numbers. But the definition are still equivalent. More importantly, though, is how do you define the real numbers without the natural numbers?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: By defining them as complete ordered field? Neither the field axioms nor the order axioms nor completeness require natural numbers.

Comment: @celtschk: But why is there even a complete ordered field? And why is it unique-enough?

Comment: Doesn't the equivalence of definition 1 with countability require the axiom of choice? I.e. to prove that the cardinal of the natural numbers is the smallest cardinal? I'm not saying your answer is wrong, just responding to @AsafKaragila

Comment: @Francis: No, you can prove without choice that $\aleph_0$ is the only infinite cardinal which is *minimal*. I never claimed, in that definition, that it is the minimum.

Comment: I'm curious how you could prove, with those definitions, things like "countable union of countable is countable".

Comment: @Martin: Assuming the axiom of choice, or without it? And I agree that these definitions are not the best for actually working in mathematics.

Comment: Your choice ;)  Or, even simpler, I cannot imagine how to show uniqueness, for instance.

Comment: @Martin: Well, this is a nifty little thing about the natural numbers, it is the unique linear order which is without a maximum, but every proper initial segment is finite. Once you establish that a finite set has no self injections which are not bijections, you immediately get a unique matching between elements based on the cardinality of the initial segments they define. This is essentially the same argument you'd use "normally", only here we hide the natural numbers as "finite cardinalities" without being too specific about them.

Comment: Ah yes, I see the distinction, I had mistakenly thought you needed choice to prove that the two definitions of countability were equivalent (which isn't the question that was asked, quite, but I was just wanting to check).

Comment: Great answer! $\;\!$

Comment: @goblin: Thanks, but there's still some 65 votes before we can say that the system agrees with you... :P

Answer (score 27):

Two sets are *equipotent* iff there is a bijection between them.

A set is *finite* iff it admits a total ordering in which every nonempty subset has a least element and a greatest element; otherwise it is *infinite*.

(Alternatively, a set $A$ is *infinite* iff the set $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A))$ is equipotent to a proper subset of itself.)

A set is *countable* (finite or countably infinite) iff all of its infinite subsets are equipotent.

Comment: I'm sure this is a stupid question, but -- why do you need to invoke $\mathcal P$? I'd have thought that a set is infinite if and only if *it* is equipotent to some proper subset of itself.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense -- thanks!

Comment: Aw, I liked the $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$ characterization ...

Comment: @bof Wouldn't it be even simpler to say that X is infinite iff X can be injected to a strict subset of itself (e.g. X minus a singleton)?

Comment: @AlexandreHalm Yes, but I wanted to avoid using the Axiom of Choice. You need AC to prove that every infinite set can be injected to a proper subset of itself. However you don't need AC to prove that the second power set $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$ of an infinite set $X$ can be injected to a proper subset of itself.

Answer (score 12):

No that does not work. Even if you add a condition that there is an element (representing $0$) that is not the successor of anything), the definition would still claim that, for example
$$ (\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z) \cup \mathbb N $$
is countable, just by defining "successor" as the usual $x\mapsto x+1$.

---

What modern (since the early 1900s) set theory *actually* does does not depend directly on the natural numbers:

> 1. A set $A$ is called *inductive* iff $\varnothing \in x$, and for every $x\in A$ it holds that $x\cup\{x\}\in A$ too.
> 2. There's an explicit axiom of set theory promising that at least one inductive set exists.
> 3. The *intersection* of all inductive sets is called $\omega$.
> 4. A set is called "countable" if it is in bijective correspondence with (some subset of) $\omega$.

It turns out that the elements of $\omega$ are good candidates for *representing* the natural numbers within set theory, so usually we end up defining $\mathbb N$ to be an alternative name for $\omega$ -- but countability does not actually depend of the number-ness of $\omega$'s elements. (It doesn't care about *arithmetic*, for example).

Comment: I agree that $\omega$ represents $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ acts as a name for $\omega$. And I know that the pure set theoretic construction of $\mathbb{N}$ exists. Actually what I am intended to ask is "Is it possible to define countability without such creatures even though they are pure set theoretic". For example defining order relation (as a consequence defining ordered set) without referring order-able numbers (or the set theoretic equivalence of such order-able numbers).

Comment: @DurgadassS: I think bof's answer is a good response to that.

Answer (score 3):

> A set $S$ is countable iff $S$ injects into every set $T$ that non-surjectively injects into $T$.

Basically, $S$ is countable iff $S$ is no larger than every infinite set.

> A set is countable if there exists a successor function as characterised above.

*Henning Makholm* already explained why this is wrong, but I wish to point out that it is because you did not get an **equivalence**. If a set is countable then there exists a successor function like you said, but the converse does not hold.

Comment: I understand your point. Also my characterisation is incomplete (or wrong). The question actually is whether it is possible to characterise such a function. If the name "successor" bothers then lets call it something like "counter function".

Comment: @DurgadassS: Hmm if you're asking about characterizing the successor function then it is a vastly different question as compared to defining countable. My answer provides a definition of countable, and it is only incidental that any successor-like operator on $T$ would be a non-surjective injection from $T$ into itself.

Comment: Yes I now realise the vast difference. However it seems this question is of significant interest and I don't disturb it.

Comment: Wait, how is this different than what bof and I wrote?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Um my answer is definitely different from *bof*'s, since his/hers is essentially "$S$ is countable iff every pair of infinite subsets of $S$ can be put in bijection." Secondly, both of your answers involve the use of linear orderings, which is not used in my answer. Also it's a more succinct definition, to a certain extent. =)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in a constructive theory, then the concepts of *denumerable* (*countable*) and *recursively enumerable* (*semidecidable*) precisely coincide, so you can avoid direct reference to the natural numbers that way.

Certainly, if a set is recursively (computably) enumerable, then it is countable. A simple counting algorithm that outputs the members of the set can be used to demonstrate this fact. This works even in a classical setting, of course.

Now, if a set is countable, then the construction (in some formal system) of its [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) provides an algorithm for deciding the set, by the Curry-Howard correspondence. Thus the set is recursive. (The Curry-Howard correspondence, by virtue of being an isomorphism, can be used to show the converse too, but I wanted to show that the converse holds even in a classical theory, as per above.)

Comment: Please explain the downvote: don't just drive by!

Comment: +1 but can you give an example of such a theory or framework? I've never heard of such a thing, though it sounds interesting.

Comment: I am unsure how one would develop the theory of recursive enumerability without mentioning natural numbers at no point. Would you mind giving some more details?

Comment: @goblin, Well, any constructive system should do the job, I believe. Specifically, intuitionistic logic.

Comment: @Wojowu, I've updated and expanded the answer, to provide clarity, but with specific regards to the mention of natural numbers: the theory of Turing machines/lambda calculus aren't too explicit about natural numbers, as far as I'm concerned. Is there anywhere in particular you see natural numbers sneaking in?

Comment: @Noldorin, I don't get that. Assuming its consistent, ZFC can't prove that every countable subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is c.e., because it can prove the negation of this statement. So IZF can't prove this either. What am I missing?

Comment: If you are dealing with Turing machines, I would argue natural numbers, or for that matter integers, come in when defining this computation model because of the tape. As for lambda calculus, I would agree natural numbers don't sneak in in any obvious way.

Comment: @Wojowu, Because of the tape, perhaps yes. But now we're getting into subtle philosophical points. Certainly the concept of successor/predecessor is involved, I'll admit that. :)

Comment: @goblin: Maybe this is a situation where ZFC (and the assumption of consistency) is too strong. Let me flip your argument: can you spot any fallacy in my reasoning above?

Comment: @Noldorin, well, for starters, I don't really know what this sentence means: "Now, if a set is countable, then the construction (in some formal system) of its characteristic function provides an algorithm for deciding the set, by the Curry-Howard correspondence." You seem to be using "set" to mean what I would call a "subset." For me, if $A$ and $B$ are sets, you can't consider $A \cup B$ or $A \cap B$, all you can consider are categorical constructions like $A \sqcup B$ and $A \times B$.

Comment: @goblin, You still need to work in some domain though, from a model-theoretic perspective. When I say characteristic function, I mean a function defined within the theory, which has a clear interpretation outside of the model.

Comment: @goblin: While this post has too little detail to be a proper answer to the question, it does 'work' in a sufficiently constructive setting where you can only prove existential statements by constructing an explicit witness, and of course you can't have anything like the axiom of infinity because it states the existence of a set that you can't construct. But such a viewpoint is only meaningful if one also rejects the notion that the halting problem is well-defined, namely that every Turing machine run on an empty tape either halts or does not halt. But the downvote is not mine.

Comment: @user21820: I don't think you need to say that about the halting problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Noldorin: Basically the question is whether you accept LEM for $Σ_1$ sentences, which is equivalent to the halting problem having well-defined truth value. It is not meaningful to accept that but reject non-constructive existential axioms such as the axiom of infinity. Feel free to come to the [logic chat-room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) so that we can have further discussion without cluttering your comment thread.